# What is the meaning of ビリビリ in this context?

Tags: meaning

Context/conversation added:

友達さん: ヒカリちゃん、なんでアニキにだけちょっと怖いも?

ヒカリちゃん: ふーん?あんたもビリビリされたいってわけ!?

ヒカリちゃん is a so-called ツンデレcharacter. アニキ is the main character of the story and ヒカリちゃん is noticeably harsher with him than with anyone else. 友達さん is curious as to why and the above is how she responds. 友達さん has a verbal quirk in where he ends his sentences with も. It is not the particle も so please treat the sentence as “なんでアニキにだけちょっと怖い ? “ .

I’m curious about the meaning of ビリビリ in this case. Any thoughts are very much appreciated. My apologies for the trouble.

Comment: Does this character have anything to do with electricity?

Comment: She is a light and fire character, but the localization translated the exchange the following manner: “"Hikari-chan, why you only mean to Aniki?" Hm? You'd rather I was mean to you?"

Answer (score 3):

[ビリビリ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8A%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8A) is an onomatopoeia for electrical shock, so it means "You wanna get an electric shock, too?" It's either she has an ability related to electricity, or she has used a tool to give アニキ an electric shock.

**EDIT:** It's not strictly limited to electricity, but can be used to describe plasma discharge, laser beam, dangerous sonic/radio wave, etc. [ヒカリ's attacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEi96KGjo2U&t=23s) can also be described using ビリビリ.

Comment: She is a light and fire character, but the localization translated the exchange the following manner: “"Hikari-chan, why you only mean to Aniki?" “Hm? You'd rather I was mean to you?"

Comment: The character is Mythra from Xenoblade 2, as I've just figured out, and this is a post-battle conversation between her and Tora. She doesn't have electric powers as far as I remember, nor does she ever shock Rex with anything, so there's no greater context to go on. https://kamikouryaku.com/xenoblade2/?%E6%88%A6%E9%97%98%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E5%90%88%E3%81%84%E9%9B%86

Comment: @Magna [Her way of attacking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEi96KGjo2U&t=23s) (energy discharging) can be described as ビリビリ.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the character, but, Hikari-chan is ツン to aniki, and gives him an electrical-shock as a part of her harshness to him. The friend asks her why she is acting so harsh only to him, (maybe 'も' is just expressing questioning tone.) and she replied as 'so you want to be attacked with my electricity, too, do you?' And it might just mean "none of your business", or "don't say unnecessary."